# githubでビルドしたファイルを管理せず公開する方法について

Tags: javascript, node.js, travis-ci, bower

現在、`bower`と`cdn.rawgit.com`を利用して、以下の様なjavascriptのライブラリを公開しています。

https://github.com/59naga/victorica#readme

この方法の場合、github上に成果物(`victorica.min.js`)を管理することになり、成果物が蓄積して[コミットが肥大化](https://github.com/59naga/victorica/commit/d28b8a26167e02c9b207cb9e6d55db642d71d965)してしまいます。

[TravisCI](https://github.com/59naga/edgy-comment-viewer) などでテスト成功時に何らかのプロバイダへアップロードを行い、cdnなどのサービスから成果物へアクセスすることは出来ないでしょうか？

現状、考えている方法として、`https://npmcdn.com/`を利用して、TravisCIから`npm publish`したファイルを、NodeJSのサーバー経由でアクセスする方法です。

https://npmcdn.com/victorica@0.0.2/lib/index.js

Comment: 質問したいことは何でしょう？その考えている方法に何か問題があるのですか？

Comment: 問題無さそうですね…。手軽さとしては申し分ないですし、`npmcdn.com`が終了してしまった時を心配しましたが、このサービスもgithub上でコードが公開されているので、最終的に自前でcdn立てれば良さそうです。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

少々遅めの反応ですが。
ソースではなくビルド結果の成果物ををリポジトリ内にcommitしたくない、という質問だと理解しました。
gitで割り当てたタグをgithubにpushすると、Releasesでタグに紐付いたリリース情報を書けるのですが、これに任意のファイルも添付できます。

私の場合、こんな感じ↓で実行可能jarを配布しています。
https://github.com/vmi/selenese-runner-java/releases

githubのAPIでも操作できるので、リリース用のスクリプトを書けば良いかと思います。

Comment: なるほど。 「[node-webkitアプリをTravis CI経由でGitHub Releaseにバイナリ登録する](http://efcl.info/2014/09/05/node-webkit-binary-release/)」を参考にしてみた感じでは、TravisCIからアップロードを行うことも可能なようですね。ただこの方法の場合、npmなどで依存として管理することが難しそうなので、場合に応じて利用してみようと思います。